# window.open() call is redirected in Google Sites

Tags: javascript, google-sites

So I have a page in Google sites with the following code inside an HTML Box:

```
<a id="resource-link" href="#">My Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("resource-link").addEventListener("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      window.open("http://www.google.com","_blank");
   });
</script>
```

I have also tried using the `onclick` attribute rather than `addEventListener()`

Works fine in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgg0ffp6/2/).

When this code is put into an HTML Box, clicking the link results in opening a new tab (what I want), however before loading `http://www.google.com`, it is redirected to the url of the original page with the link on it.

P.S. I really hate Google Sites and all its nonsense.

**UPDATE:**
the reason I am not using a simple `<a href="..."></a>` is because I need to open multiple tabs with a single click. The single call to `window.open(google)` is just an example.

**UPDATE 2:**

changing the code to:

```
<a onClick="open_resources()">My Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var open_resources = function(){
    window.open("http://www.google.com","_blank");
  };
</script>
```

results in the following error:

```
Uncaught script error: Uncaught TypeError: Expected property "open" to be a function, not undefined: undefined in source: "<click handler>" at line: -1
```

Comment: If you hate it why are you using it?

Comment: Check this out, it's a hack but might work for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/30512485/24839

Comment: nope. still redirects to Sites.

Comment: now that you mention it, no, the click handler isn't firing. Nor does it fire when switching back to an `onclick="function()` method. I can't find anything about clickhandlers and Google Sites when searching

Answer (score 0):

You could change the element from an `anchor` to a `span` and style it to look like a link:

head

```
<style>
    #resource-link{
        color: blue;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
</style>
```

body

```
<span id="resource-link">My Link</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("resource-link").addEventListener("click", function(e){
     window.open("http://www.google.com","_blank");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer could be to have the first link in the anchor tag and other ones in the click handler, like this:

```
<a id="resource-link" href="http://www.site1.com" target="_blank">My Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("resource-link").addEventListener("click", function(e){
      window.open("http://www.site2.com","_blank");
      window.open("http://www.site3.com","_blank");
      // ...
   });
</script>
```

Comment: properly opens site1, but click handler is still not called.

Comment: are you sure something in google sites isn't preventing your javascript or your click handler? have you added alert/log statements to see if it reaches them?

Comment: I'm sure the problem is something I don't understand about Google Sites. If you look at my update, I have another piece of code that should do the same thing. Neither are successfully calling my click handler. Are you aware of any restrictions on event listeners or the `onClick` attribute in Google Sites? I could not find any in my searches

Comment: not that I'm aware of. are scripts working at all (put an alert statment outside the click hanlder)? and are you sure javascript is enabled on your browser?

Comment: Javascript is enabled on my browser. Is there something I need to do to make JS work on Sites? I get the following when putting `alert("Hello!");` within the script tags: `Uncaught script error: "alert" is not defined in this scope. in source: "unknown" at line: 0`